# Error whle running python script from Java

Tags: java, python-3.x

I have been trying to invoke a Python 3.x program from Java. What I need is to get output from python and write it to a file. This is what I have done. This is creating a Json file but does not gives the output. Please help me out here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, IOException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python <path to the file>/reg.py");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String ret = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(ret);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("<some path>/output.json"));
    out.write(ret);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Try flushing the writer before closing like out.flush().

Comment: Tried. but it is giving the same output that is 'null'. But when I run this file directly from the command line, it is giving the desired output.

Comment: You mean your json contains "null".

Comment: this seems to be more of a problem in your python code then, does it read relative paths or anything like that?

Comment: You are reading only one line. Does the python script outputs the complete JSON into one single line?

Comment: @Santosh, no the JSON file is coming out empty, 'null' is what I am getting on the console of my Java editor along with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
 at invoke.RunPython.main(RunPython.java:22)"

Comment: @mnesarco, no it is about 4 lines of output, but it should atleast give me the first line.

Comment: I would do two things: first, check from the console if "python <path to the file>/reg.py" returns some output. Check if <path to the file> is absolute. Then, replace in your code, python call with for example "echo blablabla" and see if blablabla appears in your output.json. We need to figure out if py script is wrong or it's invocation.

Comment: Are you sure the python script is printing to `stdout` and not to `stderr`? In the latter case you'd need to read from `p.getErrorStream()`.

Comment: have you tried: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<path to python>/python <path to the file>/reg.py");

Comment: @mate00, I just checked , it is throwing errors if I run the code like this :"python <path to the file>/reg.py". But if I am going directly into the directory from terminal  and running it, it works totally fine.

Comment: Does your Java program have the required permissions to execute and write to the target directory (Assuming you are using a *nix OS)?

Comment: And what errors do you get? Can you paste it here?

Comment: @mate00:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path to the file>/reg.py", line 170, in <module>
    send()
  File "/<path to the file>reg.py", line 12, in send
    lines = open("output.txt",encoding="utf-8").readlines()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.txt'

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I am on windows 10

Comment: @mnesarco tried, did not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after our talk in the comments, your script throws an error because it cannot find a file output.txt. Now, the thing is that this is logged to an error stream not the regular one. What you should do is to open that stream and read it:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

In fact, you could open both streams: errorStream and outputStream and read error stream first to check if it contains something (it means that execution failed). If it doesn't, open outputStream and read its contents normally.